# Get top 2 highest values of every group

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I have tried many stack over flow answers from similar questions but none worked.
I have a table of the form

```
Class      nva

abc        128.5
yty        1,230.7
jhuh       399.7
abc        78.6
abc        962.7
yty        788.6
jhuh       88.8
```

So in class row I am having three values of abc. I want 2 columns in decreasing order of nva. So the sample output will be like:

```
Class       nva

abc         962.7
abc         128.5
abc         78.6
yty         1,230.7
yty         788.6
jhuh        399.7
jhuh        88.8
```

Comment: groupby with nlargest

Comment: hmmm, here is first problem your column `nva` contains strings, so need `df['nva'] = df['nva'].str.replace(',','').astype(float)` or `df = pd.read_csv(file, thousands=',')` and then `df = df.sort_values(['Class','nva'], ascending=[True, False]).groupby('Class').head(2)`

Comment: 94.41  91.38  9.81 79.98 783.79 76.62 This is how I get nva values when I sort